# how to use $uibTooltipProvider in popover of angular UI bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using popover directive to display popover. I have multiple pop over in my code.
But as per requirement, we need to show only one pop up open at one time.
After googling, I found that we can use $uibTooltipProvider.option (popover-mode : single). But I am not sure how to use this inside my code.
I am using angular 1.5 with typescript.
My pop over code is as follows:

```
<span class="invoke-popup " popover-placement="left " 
    uib-popover-template="$ctrl.dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
    popover-is-open="$ctrl.isPopOverOpen[$index] ">
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to config your tooltips on a global scale, you should do it inside the `.config()` function, there you can inject the `$uibTooltipProvider`.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($uibTooltipProvider) {
    $uibTooltipProvider.options({
        'property' : 'value'
    });
});
```

There you can pass properties that will affect all you tooltips. So you can try there.
Although I'm not sure how `popover-mode` works exactly!

Comment: Remember to do not put the `tooltip` attribute prefix in the object property name.

Comment: @aUXcoder Thanks for pointing this out. This was exactly my issue.